# How to translate the url in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, django-i18n

I'm trying to translate the entire Django Admin including the url from **English** to **French**.

This is my `django-project` below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  |-admin.py
 |  └-apps.py
 |-my_app2
 └-locale
    └-fr
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          |-django.po
          └-django.mo
```

And, this is `core/settings.py` below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French'))
)
```

And, this is `core/urls.py` below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
)
```

And, this is `my_app1/models.py` below:

```py
# "my_app1/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=_("name"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('person')
        verbose_name_plural = _('persons')
```

And, this is `my_app1/apps.py` below:

```py
# "my_app1/apps.py"

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyApp1Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_app1'
    verbose_name = _('my_app1')
```

And, this is `locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` below:

```
# "locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po"

...

#: .\core\settings.py:140
msgid "English"
msgstr "Anglais"

#: .\core\settings.py:141
msgid "French"
msgstr "Français"

#: .\my_app1\apps.py:7
msgid "my_app1"
msgstr "mon_app1"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:6
msgid "name"
msgstr "nom"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:12
msgid "person"
msgstr "personne"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:13
msgid "persons"
msgstr "personnes"

...
```

But, the url is not translated as shown below:

```
http://localhost:8000/fr/admin/my_app1/person/add/
```

[image]

So, how can I translate the url in Django Admin?